# Can't able to install Seurat in Rstudio

Tags: r, seurat

I need to install seurat new version. I have tried by direction of Satija Lab guideline and by different youtube video. I have install R and R studio and R tool kit. I am very new in programming and have not much knowledge.
That is what I got after commend. What should I do now. Please help.

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18) -- "**Camp Pontanezen**"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
> install.packages("seurat")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/tosh/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘seurat’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
  Perhaps you meant ‘Seurat’ ?
> install.packages("Seurat")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/tosh/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/Seurat_4.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2760190 bytes (2.6 MB)
downloaded 2.6 MB

package ‘Seurat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\tosh\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsvsY5N\downloaded_packages

Please help anybody to install seurat properly. Thank you so much in advance.
```

Comment: Do `library(Seurat)` and use it -- it installed fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. @Dirk did you mean to run above comment in Rstudio? here the result> library("seurat")
Error in library("seurat") : there is no package called ‘seurat’

Comment: it's `library(Seurat)`, note the capital letter `S`

Comment: And _look at the code you posted yourself_ as it *has* the correct use:  `install.packages("Seurat")`.

Comment: I have tried in capital form "S" also but unfortunately same result. Now I have reinstalled Rstudio and try to install from their package. But one msg come before installation "Do U want to install from sources the packages which need compilation ?" What does actual mean? I will share all output just a few min.Thanks

Comment: > library(Seurat)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Seurat’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘fansi’
> detach("package:Seurat", unload = TRUE)
Error in detach("package:Seurat", unload = TRUE) : 
  invalid 'name' argument